# Add JButton to JScrollPame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have the following code taken from GeeksforGeeks that displays the contents of a 2-d array in JTable using JScrollPane:

```
public class JTableExamples { 
// frame 
JFrame f; 
// Table 
JTable j; 

// Constructor 
JTableExamples() 
{ 
    // Frame initiallization 
    f = new JFrame(); 

    // Frame Title 
    f.setTitle("JTable Example"); 

    // Data to be displayed in the JTable 
    String[][] data = { 
        { "Kundan Kumar Jha", "4031", "CSE" }, 
        { "Anand Jha", "6014", "IT" } 
    }; 

    // Column Names 
    String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Roll Number", "Department" };

    // Initializing the JTable 
    j = new JTable(data, columnNames); 
    j.setBounds(30, 40, 200, 300); 

    // adding it to JScrollPane 
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(j); 
    f.add(sp); 
    // Frame Size 
    f.setSize(500, 200); 
    // Frame Visible = true 
    f.setVisible(true); 
}
```

What I am trying to do is add a simple Component (like JButton) underneath the table but it does not seem to work. I tried modifying the code by adding the JButton to JPanel and adding JPanel to the frame:

```
   JButton button = new JButton("Back");
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.add(button);
   f.add(sp);
   f.add(panel);
```

But this simply deletes the entire table and replaces it with a single button. I also tried adding the button to JPanel and adding that JPanel to JScrollPane:

```
   JButton button = new JButton("Back");
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.add(button);
   sp.add(panel);
   f.add(sp);
```

But this did not seem to change anything. I also tried to tinker with preferred and maximum size of JScrollPanel to no avail - it always occupies the entire screen and prevents JButton from appearing on the screen.

Not shooting for design here, just functionality: have a JButton appear underneath my JTable. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default layout manager of a JFrame is the `BorderLayout`.

```
f.add(sp);
f.add(panel);
```

When you don't specify a constraint for the `BorderLayout` the `CENTER` is assumed. You can only have a single component added to the `CENTER`.

Instead your code should be:

```
f.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
f.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Note the default layout manager for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout`. So the button will be horizontally centered in the panel.

Also, instead of using a JPanel, try adding the button directly to the `PAGE_END` of the frame to see the difference.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples for using each of the different layout managers to understand the differences of the above suggestions.

Edit:

> Is there a way to decrease the height of the table

If you know you have a small table then you can use:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

This will make the scroll pane the size of the table.

Then you use:

```
//f.setSize(500, 200); 
f.pack();
```

Now all components will be displayed at their preferred size.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much! One last question: the button now appears at the very bottom of the page (I guess this is what PAGE_END does) while the (mostly) empty table continues to occupy almost the entire page. Is there a way to decrease the height of the table (remove empty space) and "lift" the button up?

Comment: *I guess this is what PAGE_END does* - don't guess! That is why I gave you the link to the Swing tutorial . The tutorial explains what the various constraints mean for each layout manager. See edit.